# Java Web Start Splash Screen Does Not Show Up

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jnlp, java-web-start

I have been digging all day in Oracle forum posts and other threads and answers to the question mentioned in the title. Is there a viable/certain answer on how to fix such an issue. My JNLP file is correct, I have tried to replace the double quote characters with single quotes and no succes.

For instance, [this test here](http://pscode.org/test/splash/) indeed works as specified by the author, but if I replace the href value of the splash image to something locally available for me (ex: ...href="http://localhost:8080/mylib/mysplash.gif"), the same splash (from the original app shows up). I have cleared temp files and everything I could think of. Again, the application mentioned here was an example of a small app which still does not do the splash image trick as I understand it should for the app.

I have tested and checked my JNLP (which I cannot reproduce here unfortunately, sorry, due to privacy issues) with available tools (from [this place](http://pscode.org/xml/xmltools.html))and it is a well-formed, well-written XML file.

The codebase reference and href reference for the image are ok.

What could be wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Andrei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "any help" :) :

- The first time your splash will not be visable
- Check that the gif file can be read by java `ImageIO.read(...)`

Comment: Although asked some time ago and this did not fix the problem at that time, i am marking this as the answer, because it was the only piece of advice i encountered in this area and also, the second bullet proved over time as a simple yet important thing to be careful about in many cases where images are involved. Thanks with some delay! :)